# How do I arrange with another column not in group_by?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dummy_data, and I want my result to be in the descending order of n1, but I'm not sure how to do that, any help would be appreciated!

```
dummy_data <- data.frame(
      a = sample(letters[1:3], 100, replace = TRUE),
      b = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 100, replace = TRUE),
      c = sample(1:2, 100, replace = TRUE),
      NO = sample(1:10, 100, replace = TRUE)
    )
    
    
    # Processing the data
    result <- dummy_data %>%
      group_by(a, b) %>%
      mutate(n1 = n_distinct(NO)) %>%
     filter(n1>3)%>%
      group_by(a, b, c) %>%
      summarize(n2 = n_distinct(NO)) %>%
      arrange(n1)
```

Comment: `summarize`, makes 1 row per group, and the only columns kept will be the grouping columns (`a`, `b`, `c`) and the columns defined in `summarize` (`n2`). If you want to use `summarize` and have `n1` in the result, you either need to include it `n1` in the grouping OR include it in the `summarize`--along with a summary function to tell `summarize` what to do with multiple values, for example `n1 = first(n1)` to keep the first one, `n1 = mean(n1)` to take the average, etc.

Comment: In this case, since `n1` should be the same for all (a, b) groups, it should also be the same for all `(a, b, c)` groups, so adding it to the `group_by` should work just fine.

Comment: you are right, I can do that